# How can I solve the following differential equation without use power series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Let we have the  following differential equation  $$y''-xy'=e^{-x}$$ how can I solve this differential equation without use power series

Comment: @RoryDaulton are you interrogating with me ?

Comment: No. Two users have voted to close this question due to lack of context and I was also asked if it should be closed. I chose to give you a chance to add more context so the question would not be closed. Would you like to add more to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Let $w=y'$ and use method of linear differential equations to solve

$$w'-xw=e^{-x}$$

Answer (score 2):

this equation can't be solved in the known elementary functions
the solution of the equation above contains the Error-function
$$w(x)=c_1 e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}
   \text{erf}\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$